# Does the respondsToSelector method have to exist?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Does a method which I check for with respondsToSelector have to actually exist?

What if I only define it in the interface part and fail to implement it? I'm looking at a poor-man's virtual function in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, yes the method actually has to exist for the check to succeed in the context you describe. `respondsToSelector:` will return `NO` if the method is not implemented.

More importantly, I think you mean a poor man's pure virtual function in Objective-C. All instance methods are "virtual" in Objective-C; since method lookup is done a run-time, the subclass' implementation will always be used, even from a pointer of the superclass type. In Objective-C, there is no such thing as a pure virtual base class. You can often achieve what you want by either using a `@protocol` to define an API or using a base class that provides an implementation that throws an `NSNotImplementedException` as its body. Subclasses would obviously have to override the implementation, making it effectively pure virtual.

Comment: Might want to edit the first line. Technically speaking, the methods does not have to exist. After all `respondsToSelector:` sole purpose is to determine whether a method does exist or not. It works fine with non-existant methods, it just returns no. I think you answer makes sense in the assumed context of the parent but for future readers you might want to make the distinction explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Given that calling `respondsToSelector:` only makes sense when you don’t know whether a method exists, it’s not entirely clear what you mean.

If you mean, does *some implementation* of a method with the specified selector have to exist somewhere, the answer is no. Selectors merely represent names of methods. The `@selector` directive doesn’t reference any aspect of any method implementation.

Answer (score 1):

respondsToSelector will return NO, since the selector isn't callable at run-time. The interface part only affects compilation.